# Tomcat server many inactive sessions with psi-probe?

Tags: java, tomcat8, probe

I'm running `tomcat8` server with a web application.

In the tomcat manager session list I can see 95 sessions, most of them shown as  inactive since several days. Eg.

```
Used time: 00:02:40
Inactive time: 48:27:51
TTL: -47:57:51

Session Max Inactive Interval 00:30:00
```

On the machine running th tomcat, I can also see all session threads running with `ps -eLf | grep java`. This gives me all the 95 threads.

Question: how can I find out why those sessions are not removed? Currently the app in in testing stage and only few are accessing the app internal. So why might they not be getting removed.

---

Update: I also ahve `psi-probe` application running for monitoring. When I opened probe and clicked on the sessions to show, suddenly all sessions >30mins where gone.

So this might be a probe issue locking the sessions in tomcat somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Since I undeployed the `probe.war` application, I never got sessions stuck. So that's probably the cause...